# How does Solr sort documents when no sorting-query is given?

Tags: solr

When selecting rows, without sorting-query, solr sort documents in the order of when those are inserted?
Will the order be unchanged permanently?
I don't use a condition like "* : *" but at least a field is specified absolutely.

Comment: its sorts based on the scoring...

Comment: If you don't specify an order the order will **not** remain "unchanged permanently".

Comment: In that case, documents are ordered randomly?

Comment: No, it's stable - but only until the index changes. If you want to have a certain order, sort by a field that represents that value..